# How can i make paginate by datatables with limit and offset?

Tags: javascript, pagination, datatables

I have a big database and so I don't want to download the full database.
So I was looking for a way how I can use the variables form the lengthMenu and the paging so that I can work with Limit and Offset in MYSQL Syntax.
Is that possible and if is not , how i can do that by javascript or anyway?
Can anybody please help me ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ it should point you in the right direction if, as I suspect, you're using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I have done this using ASP.Net MVC and jquery datatable. If you want then I can write the solution.